# procedure to check if dates of new row overlaps with existing dates in the table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to write a procedure to check if parameters given (dates) lie between any of the existing dates in the table. And if not insert new row.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test(date1 IN DATE, date2 IN DATE) AS 
  ddate1 DATE;
  ddate2 DATE;
  quer VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN 
  SELECT fdate, tdate INTO ddate1, ddate2 FROM dataHolder; 
  IF (ddate1 < date1) AND (ddate2 > date2) THEN
    quer := 'invalid'; 
  ELSE 
    INSERT INTO dataHolder VALUES (date1, date2);
    quer := 'success';
  END IF; 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(quer); 
END;
/
```

I have tried something like this but when executed I get this error:

```
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because your select statement returns more than one record. To simplify the process you could use `merge` statement and rewrite your procedure as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test(date1 IN DATE, date2 IN DATE) AS
BEGIN
  merge into Dataholder dh
  using dual
     on ((date1 < dh.fdate) and (date2 < dh.tdate))
  when not matched then
    insert (dh.fdate, dh.tdate)
      values(date1, date2);
  if sql%rowcount > 0
  then
    dbms_output.put_line('success');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('invalid');
  end if;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your select statement fetches more than record whereas your code expects only one, since you're fetching into single-value variables. You could use BULK COLLECT and collect all the dates into a collection of dates, but I think you can improve on it with the code below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test(date1 IN DATE, date2 IN DATE) AS 
  ddate1 DATE;
  ddate2 DATE;
  invalidRecords NUMBER := 0;
  quer VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(1) INTO invalidRecords FROM dataHolder WHERE fdate < date1 AND tdate > date2; 

   IF (invalidRecords > 0) THEN
     quer := 'invalid'; 
   ELSE
     INSERT INTO dataHolder VALUES (date1, date2);
     quer := 'success';
   END IF;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(quer); 
END;
/
```

Since COUNT(1) will always return just one record, it will never throw an ORA-01422 error. Also, it will always return data, so you don't need to worry about NO_DATA_FOUND, as the value 0 will be fetched if there are no invalid records.

Answer (score 0):

Some small optmization of Nuno Guerreiro's answer

```
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO invalidRecords 
FROM dual 
WHERE exists 
  (SELECT 1 FROM dataHolder WHERE fdate < date1 AND tdate > date2);
```

It will allow to keep out of counting.